# Generating an AWS Signature v4 signature for uploading to s3 (migration from v2)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I currently have a working implementation that works as follows:

UI select a file => click upload => call to my backend API to request a signature since I don't want to expose my access + secretkey => return the signature + policy => do an upload to s3.

This works fine and dandy for v2.

```
String base64Policy = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(policy.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")).replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");

        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1"));
        String signature = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(hmac.doFinal(base64Policy.getBytes("UTF-8"))).replaceAll("\n", "");
```

Now I get to the fun bit where my new buckets are in a region where v2 isn't supported.

I was following the AWS documentation but I think I am misunderstanding the payload bit a bit. Do I really need to have my UI pass in a sha256 hash of my whole file? Since that would seem to be a bit of a pain, especially since my files can be > 1 gig.

The code I was attempting to use:

```
        byte[] signatureKey = getSignatureKey(secretKey, LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")),  bucketRegion, "s3");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : signatureKey) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }

private static byte[] getSignatureKey(String key, String dateStamp, String regionName, String serviceName) throws Exception {
        byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + key).getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] kDate = HmacSHA256(dateStamp, kSecret);
        byte[] kRegion = HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
        byte[] kService = HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
        byte[] kSigning = HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);
        return kSigning;
    }



private static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception {
        String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    }
```

But this gives an invalid signature response when I try to use the rest of my code.

Am I derping that hard, and just misunderstanding: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html ?

Any help would be much appreciated since I've been hanging my head against this way too long and I'd prefer not to overhaul too much.

Comment: why not generate a presigned url and pass it to the client ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Comment: The string-to-sign is different for form `POST` uploads.  You're supposed to be signing a base64 encoded policy document: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I saw that, some documentation was a bit contradictory in that regards. (some sample code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upload a file to S3 by using standard SDK methods without generating a signature, please see the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html).
But if you need a signature for some reason, I think, the simplest way to generate a signature is to use methods from AWS SDK, please see the following class which extends `AWS4Signer`:

```
public class AwsAuthUtil extends AWS4Signer {
    private String serviceName;
    private AWSCredentials credentials;
    private String region;

    public AwsAuthUtil(AWSCredentials credentials, String region, String serviceName) {
        this.credentials = credentials;
        this.region = region;
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
    }

    public String getSignature(String policy, LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        try {
            String dateStamp = dateTime.format(ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
            return Hex.encodeHexString(hmacSha256(newSigningKey(credentials, dateStamp, region, serviceName), policy));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error", e);
        }
    }

    private byte[] hmacSha256(byte[] key, String data) throws Exception {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256.name());
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256.name()));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

where `AWS4Signer` is from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.213</version>
</dependency>
```

and `AWSCredentials` can be built as

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(s3AccessKey, s3SecretKey);
```

Also you should consider http headers when you use multipart data, for example, please see the following method which builds [HttpEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html)

```
public HttpEntity buildPostMultipartDataEntity(String objectKey, byte[] data, String signature, LocalDateTime dateTime) {

    String dateTimeStr = dateTime.format(ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"));
    String date = dateTime.format(ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));

    return MultipartEntityBuilder
        .create()
        .addTextBody("key", objectKey)
        .addTextBody("Policy", policy)
        .addTextBody("X-Amz-Signature", signature)
        .addTextBody("X-Amz-Algorithm", algorithm)
        .addTextBody("X-Amz-Date", dateTimeStr)
        .addTextBody("X-Amz-Credential", String.format("%s/%s/%s/s3/aws4_request", accessKey, date, region))
        .addBinaryBody("file", data)
        .build();
}
```

Comment: This gives me: 
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

In this case what's the inputted policy? In my old code it was:
JsonObject policy = Json.createObjectBuilder()... and then the base64 bit.

Comment: In my case it was a text file with
    {
      "expiration": "2099-12-30T12:00:00.000Z",
      "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "bucket-name"},
        ["starts-with", "$key", ""],
        ["starts-with", "$x-amz-date", ""],
        ["starts-with", "$x-amz-credential", ""],
        {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"}
      ]
    }

And I read it as 

String policy = StreamUtils.copyToString((new ClassPathResource("policy.txt")).getInputStream(), UTF_8);

Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(policy.getBytes("UTF8"));

Comment: @status and that works fine for you? And is it possible to mail me a sample of your project code (the relevant bit)/copy the code to a class file and upload it somewhere so I can test it out myself? Would save me a lot of headache. Thank you

Comment: @KristofPlennings I updated the answer with required http headers in my case and can provide some test file later.

Comment: @KristofPlennings Also please see the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html. Perhaps you do not need generating a signature at all. I generated the signature only to get POST event from S3.

Comment: @Status sorry for the late reply. Internet died. The reason I'm generating the signature is that I want to do UI => S3 bucket. Since otherwise I run into the whole 30s connection disconnect. So all the java bit does is generate the signature + policy to be used by my frontend.

Comment: If I understand the question @KristofPlennings wants the client to do the upload not the server.

Comment: @strongjz correct. The server should just be generating the signature so the credentials aren't stored on the client.

Comment: @statut the sample project would be much appreciated.

Comment: @KristofPlennings please see here: https://github.com/statut/aws-s3-signature-test

Test file SignatureTest

Comment: Cheers. That helped me sort it out. Looks like some linebreaks ended up in my policy which shouldn't be there. It also helped me clean up my code a bit.