# How to build Amazon S3 Presigned PostPolicy for file uploading in Java SDK 2.0?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I need to generate an AWS Signature v4 signature for uploading to s3, like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html.

I tried a lot of examples, but have the error

```xml
<Error>
    <Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
    <Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>ASIA2AKMADUN</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <RequestId>E68a1B73B15</RequestId>
    <HostId>fIG19S=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I tried to build signature, using `minio-java`, like this https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/PresignedPostPolicy.java

Also, I tried this code snippet https://gist.github.com/phstudy/3523576726d74a0410f8

P.S. My real target is uploading files from clients with limit of file size, like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25991275/limit-size-of-objects-while-uploading-to-amazon-s3-using-pre-signed-url), or there [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49082015/generating-an-aws-signature-v4-signature-for-uploading-to-s3-migration-from-v2). I can create [presignS3UploadLink](https://github.com/aaronanderson/aws-java-sdk-v2-utils), but there is not way to set max size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, solution https://github.com/minio/minio-java/blob/master/examples/PresignedPostPolicy.java did not work, because of absent `x-amz-security-token` parameter.

We need to use `session-token` (which we get from amazon) for creating a POST-Policy and for form publishing - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html

Sample code for minio:

```java
conditions.add(new String[]{"eq", "$x-amz-security-token", sessionToken});
formData.put("x-amz-security-token", sessionToken);
```

P.S. `x-amz-security-token` is needed because of using of temporary security credentials - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html